# iOS - How to check if a modal view is present

Tags: ios, view, modal-dialog

Is there a way to check if a modal view is present? I'd like to run a method only if a modal view is present. Also, if I have multiple modal views, is there a way to check if a certain modal view is present.

I use the following code to present and dismiss modal views:

```
    [self presentModalViewController:myModalView animated:YES];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Thank you in advance!

Cheers,
Evan

PS. My modal view has a view controller, but I'd like to check if the modal view is present from a separate class that is running asynchronously.

Comment: Please consider changing the correct answer for this question.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Are you checking the presence of a modal view controller from the parent view controller? If so, you can just check that view controller's modalViewController property:

```
BOOL modalPresent = (self.modalViewController);
```

If you want to check for a particular modal view controller, you can get the modal view controller's class name like this:

```
NSString *modalClassName = NSStringFromClass([self.modalViewController class]);
```

Comment: self.modalViewController is now deprecated, you should now use BOOL modalPresent = (BOOL)(self.presentedViewController);

Comment: To piggyback on @allaire's comment, here's the documentation on presentedViewController (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/presentedViewController) that seems to suggest a modal view controller exists only if it is being presented by "this" view.

Answer (score 64):

You can check using: `self.presentedViewController`, which returns `The view controller that is presented by this view controller, or one of its ancestors in the view controller hierarchy.`

Comment: this should be the checked answer. `modalViewController` is deprecated

Comment: Use `presentedViewController` now.

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me is following:

```
// this is the trick: set parent view controller as application's window root view controller
UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window.rootViewController = viewController;

// assert no modal view is presented
XCTAssertNil(viewController.presentedViewController);

// simulate button tap which shows modal view controller
[viewController.deleteButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// assert that modal view controller is presented
XCTAssertEqualObjects(viewController.presentedViewController.class, MyModalViewController.class);
```

As far as I tested it, this works for iOS7 and iOS8. Didn't try on iOS6 however.

Comment: Don't forget to add the UINavigationController as the window's rootViewController if your UIViewController is embedded in one. Then just call presentedViewController on that navController. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the presence of a modal `view controller` from the parent `view controller`

```
if ( [[self presentingViewController] presentingViewController] ) {

}
```